# How do I perform maintenance on a master DNS/DHCP (BIND9/ISC-DHCP) Ubuntu server?

Tags: 12.04, dhcp, bind, maintenance, failover

I'm running non-GUI Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS (64-bit) on my 2 DNS/DHCP servers.

Both servers are running BIND9 9.8.1-P1 and ISC-DHCP-SERVER 4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.6.
Please note that for DNS I'm running them in a master/slave configuration, and for DHCP they are running a failover configuration.

Ideally, I'd like to perform maintenance on the master/primary first, and once it's back up and running, I'd like to then take care of the secondary/slave. Maintenance will consist of installing various updates and performing a restart.

I'm uncertain how to gracefully bring each machine down without losing/interrupting service. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Close-voters: **Why** is it unclear what he is asking? The Title says it already.

Comment: I've done a lot of research on this topic already (I'm the person that built the 2 Ubuntu 12.04 servers from scratch to replace our 8 year old DNS/DHCP server that was on its last legs). That said, I'm not a Linux System Admin, I'm merely wearing the hat at the moment. I'm well aware that BIND9 doesn't care about being stopped since the slave contains all of the same zone files (provided automatic zone transfer is functional, which it is). I'm uncertain on how to address the failover aspect however, as I was under the impression RNDC commands have to be issued for a partner-down state.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.